# Declare array of custom type

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm triying to declare an array of custom type that I created. This type is formed by 2 int32 variables. I'm triying do that with this command:

> main::myType[] myarray;

where main is my package name. When I compiled the program I received an error

Which is the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186836/declare-array-of-custom-type/) by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct format for message-type in a .msg file is

```
package_name/data_type_name[] variable name
```

Where **data_type_name** is a message in the package **package_name**

eg.

```
std_msgs/Float64[] values
```

Note that this is not a regular array in c++.

After generating the msg file, if you look at the .h file for that message, you will find that values is a vector of doubles.

```
std::vector <double> values;
```

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2014-07-21**:
Thanks, I will do it.